# My npm start for react is not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to learn react, but i can not start npm. Here is my code :

**Error :**

```
user:~/reactApp$ sudo npm start

> reactapp@1.0.0 start /home/user/reactApp
> webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --inline --content-base .

events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 172.27.27.227:3000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1031:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1052:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1350:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1523:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:102:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --inline --content-base .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2018-02-19T10_56_13_668Z-debug.log
```

**Logs :**

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v9.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~prestart: reactapp@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: reactapp@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/user/reactApp/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/user/reactApp
10 silly lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --inline --content-base .' ]
11 silly lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --inline --content-base .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid reactapp@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/user/reactApp
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-104-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v9.2.0
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --inline --content-base .`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

~

**package.json**

```
  {
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --inline --content-base ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
      path:'/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 3000
   },
   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
module.exports = config;
```

tried, but can not find any solution, could anyone help me to understand what is going on, and where is error ? let me know if you all need more information for debugging this issue . Thanks

**Edit :** already checked, by change port

Answer (score 2):

From the error, it seems like you are trying to use a port that's already in use. You must either change the port or you must kill a process which is using that port.

You can change the port like so:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 4000 --inline --content-base ."
  },
```

Or find who is listening on port 3000 like so `lsof -i :3000` and then kill the process `kill <Process ID>`. I hope this helps.

Comment: @rash-tay Nothing found for `lsof -i :3000` or `lsof -i :4000`

Comment: both ports are free, no process id found for port 3000 or port 4000

Comment: You won't find port 4000 being used because I asked you to use it instead. Try `sudo lsof -i TCP:3000 | grep LISTEN`. Also, try restarting your system and then running `npm start`

Comment: One of the reason can also be that the IP address (172.27.27.227) isn't one your server is using. Recheck if the IP address is correct. Maybe you can stick to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`.